# React Animated - translateX not working

Tags: css, reactjs

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? I'm using [React Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/animated.html):

```
<Animated.span
        style={{ transform: [{ translateX: 50 }], cursor: 'pointer'...
```

According to the react docs:

> ```
> transform?: [
>   {perspective: number},
>   {rotate: string},
>   {rotateX: string},
>   {rotateY: string},
>   {rotateZ: string},
>   {scale: number},
>   {scaleX: number},
>   {scaleY: number},
>   {translateX: number},
>   {translateY: number},
>   {skewX: string},
>   {skewY: string}
> ]
> ```

However, the transform isn't being applied.

If I apply `scale: 0.8` instead of `translateX`, it works fine - so is there a problem with the way I'm setting the `translateX` value? I've also tried setting `translate`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: 50 what? You have to have a *measure* as well as a *number* surely. `px`, `%` what?

Comment: @Paulie_D React can work without units. And specifying units there would imply the type to be string.

Comment: I find that odd...you're attempting a transform but without specifying how far. Is there a default? Also, `span`s need to be `inline-block` to accept a `transform`.

Comment: I find it odd, too - I'd tried passing '50%', and '50px', but checked against the docs and saw I should be passing a number rather than a string - which you're right, is strange.

And I have display set to inline-block already. :)